# Replacing part of a string automatically based on user input

Tags: php

Ok so in Python, I could have a URL like

```
"(www.google.com/%s)" % cat
```

and the output would be

```
"(www.google.com/cat)"
```

How do I do this in PHP? I don't want to echo the output out, I want to scrape a given URL based on user input (i.e., they put in a stock ticker and it will go to the page of that stock ticker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) (or possibly `vsprintf`, if that would be more convenient).

```
$url = sprintf("(www.google.com/%s)", "cat");
echo $url;                                    // result: (www.google.com/cat)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't actually have to do that, I just split the URL in two and concatenated it back with the ticker inside. Though I may try this method too! I don't know which is more efficient.